# SimpleCursorTreeAdapter causing an error

Tags: android, simplecursortreeadapter

Below is the code from my actvity along with a inner class that is a sub-class of Simple Cursor Tree Adapter. The problem is when i click child elements of the There is an error

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SQLiteDatabase db = new ToDoDatabase(getApplicationContext())
            .getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, ToDoDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, null,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    CustomCursorTreeAdapter cursorTreeAdapter = new CustomCursorTreeAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), cursor, R.layout.group_item_layout,
            new String[] { ToDoDatabase.TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE },
            new int[] { R.id.groupItem }, R.layout.child_item_layout,
            new String[] { ToDoDatabase.TASK_TIME },
            new int[] { R.id.childItem });
    drawerList.setAdapter(cursorTreeAdapter);
}

public class CustomCursorTreeAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    public CustomCursorTreeAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
            int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor group) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new ToDoDatabase(getApplicationContext())
                .getWritableDatabase();
        return db
                .query(
                        ToDoDatabase.TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[] { ToDoDatabase.TASK_TIME },
                        ToDoDatabase.TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE + " = ? ",
                        new String[] { group.getString(group
                                .getColumnIndex(ToDoDatabase.TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE)) },
                        null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The output from my logcat is as below. More over I am getting same value for expendableList groupitem. Example if i there are tWo "A" then i am getting 2 "A" with same childitems.And i am a android beginner

```
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:515)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.getId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:436)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getChildId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:173)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getItemId(ExpandableListConnector.java:427)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(AdapterView.java:756)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.widget.AdapterView.setSelectedPositionInt(AdapterView.java:1128)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3165)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5604)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2054)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1815)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1917)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1376)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:255)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1865)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5784)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at          com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
     10-14 23:52:11.908: E/AndroidRuntime(28080):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `getChildrenCursor` does not return `Cursor` with column called `_id`

Comment: Yes this was the problem thank you. Can u help me with the second problem i mentioned about multiple same groupItems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Selvin says, it appears you have an invalid return on your `getChildrenCursor()` method.

Refer to the documentation on the method.

> The Cursors must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html

Comment: Yes this was the problem thank you. Can u help me with the second problem i mentioned about multiple same groupItems @Demonslay

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question. Are you getting duplicate results when there are not supposed to be? I see you are using the `distinct` variant of the `query` method; the `distinct` only works if you pass a column to the `groupBy` argument so that it can compare to.

Comment: What i need to pass in groupBy? The case is that I want unique dates. i am not able to achieve that @Demonslay335

Comment: I'm not completely sure on which of your columns is the date you are wanting to group by, but I'd assume it to be `TASK_TIME` or `TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE`. You'd pass it as a string array as the other arguments: 
`new String[] { ToDoDatabase.TASK_TIME }`

Comment: Whoops, my mistake, `groupBy` is a singular String, not an array. Simply pass the `TASK_NAME_FORMATE_DATE` constant and you should be good. You may need to define the `columns` argument if that alone does nothing.

Comment: No it didnt solved the problem. I am still getting multiple columns and this time i am getting only one `TASK_TIME` associated with `TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE`

Comment: thank you! clear info and solve the problem with the exception:
i've got the same exception. and stubmled over "at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.getId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:436)" in the stacktrace. so the answer with missed "_id" was right and helpful!